# Best way to get daily step count from Apple Health Kit

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am interested in obtaining the summary numbers of steps per day from Health Kit. Is there a way to do this without having to query for individual `HKQuantitySample`s and then summing up the data by day myself?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` (reference documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery)) to compute the total number of steps taken per day.